# Using Inverse probability of CENSORING weights with already ps-matched data

Tags: r, survival, propensity-scores, censoring, weighted-regression

EDIT according to Willems2016---------------

I have data of treated and untreated persons of which the covariate `age` (assume there is just one covariate) is balanced using propensity score matching (treat ~ age).
Thus, assume the following data as an already propensity score matched sample:

```
data <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  time = c(12, 25, 27, 31, 67, 74, 80, 84, 90, 102),
  event = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  treat = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  age = c(39, 41, 49, 37, 48, 39, 41, 49, 37, 48)
)
```

Variable `event` is coded 1 for a person who suffered an event, and 0 if the person was censored.

**How can one derive inverse probability of censoring weights (IPCW)?**

First, we need to create a new variable called `censored` which is the inverse of `event` as:

```
data$censored <- 1 - data$event
```

Variable that indicates the beginning of an interval:

```
data$start <- 0
```

Sort follow-up times in ascending order:

```
times <- sort(unique(data$time))
```

Apply the function survSplit{Survival} to the `event` indicator and sort in chronological order per `id`:

```
library(survival)
data.long <- survSplit(data,
                       cut = times,
                       end = "time",
                       start = "start",
                       event = "event",
                       id = "new_id")

data.long <- data.long[
  order(data.long$new_id,
    data.long$time),
]
```

Repeat for the censoring indicator and sort in chronological order per `id`.

```
data.long.cens <- survSplit(data,
                            cut = times,
                            end = "time",
                            start = "start",
                            event = "censored",
                            id = "new_id")

data.long.cens <- data.long.cens[order(data.long.cens$id,
                                   data.long.cens$time),
]
```

Add the adjusted censoring indicator to the long data format:

```
data.long$censored <- data.long.cens$censored
```

Rename time into `stop` {dplyr}:

```
library(dplyr)
data.long <- data.long %>%
  rename(stop = time)
```

Fitting Cox model for time to censoring. Now we use `treat` as an independent variable as `treat` was used before as a dependent variable to calculate the ps model for matching. So `treat` also can influence censoring.

```
CZ <- coxph(Surv(start,
                 stop,
                 censored) ~ age + treat,
            data = data.long)
```

Probability of remaining uncensored:

```
data.long$KZti <- NULL

for(i in 1:nrow(data.long)) {
  datai <- data.long[i,]
  sfiCZ <- survfit(CZ, newdata = datai, type = "kaplan-meier")
  ssfiCZ <- summary(sfiCZ,
                    times = datai$start)
  data.long$KZti[i] <- ssfiCZ$surv
}
IDs <- unique(data.long$id)

KZti <- NULL

for(i in IDs) {
  datai <- subset(data.long, id == i)
  sfiCZ <- survfit(CZ, newdata = datai[1,])
  ssfiCZ <- summary(sfiCZ,
                    times = datai$start)
  KZti <- c(KZti, ssfiCZ$surv)
}
data.long$KZti <- KZti
```

IPC weights:

```
data.long$Weight <- 1/data.long$KZti
```

Cox Model:

```
ipcwmodel <- coxph(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ treat, data = data.long, weights = Weight)
```

The data was balanced in terms of variable `age` using propensity score matching (SMD: 0).
The IPC weights alter the SMD: 0.0417. Is this a problem?

```
formula <- treat ~ age
bal.tab(formula, data = data.long,
        weights = data.long$Weight,
        binary = "std", 
        continuous = "std",
        thresholds = c(m = 0.1))
```

I would be pleased to receive suggestions and feedback regarding the procedure.
Further, i used `treat` as an independent variable for the Cox model ((start,stop,censored) ~ age + treat). But does that make sense, since i use `treat` again in the final censoring-adjusted model ((start, stop, event) ~ treat)?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your scenario somewhat, is it not the case that you've ps-matched your data specifically so you can just calculate the average outcome in treated and control and the difference is then an estimator of your ATE? 

Conversely, if your data wasn't ps matched, then you could not do the above and you've have to construct an IPW estimator.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is about an additional weighting to adjust for dependent censoring, therefore IPCW.

Comment: I used `CausalGAM::estimate.ATE()` for an augmented inverse propensity weighted (AIPW) estimator. By manipulating the family argument, perhaps it is possible to fit Cox models too.

Comment: The analysis is exceedingly inefficient and fails to take into account how easy it is to adjust for age without assuming linearity and without matching and the resulting discarding of valuable observations.

Comment: @FrankHarrell This is an extremely simplified example. Imagine this with 100 covariates. I understand your point, related to this example

Comment: See https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.7021